# `method_missing': undefined local variable or method `authentication_keys' error when installing devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, devise

I'm trying to get Devise up and running.  I'm using devise 1.0.10 and rails 2.3.8, on an otherwise pretty clean hostingrails install.

When I run `ruby script/generate devise_install`

I get the following error message.  Has anyone seen this before.  Any ideas how to proceed with the install?  I searched around and hit a wall.

Thanks,  Tim

ruby script/generate devise_install
/home/p7017r10/appname/config/environment.rb:4: warning: already initialized constant RAILS_ENV
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p369/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:1994:in `method_missing': undefined local variable or method`authentication_keys' for # (NameError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p369/gems/devise-1.0.5/lib/devise/models/validatable.rb:18:in `included'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p369/gems/devise-1.0.5/lib/devise/models/validatable.rb:16:in`class_eval'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p369/gems/devise-1.0.5/lib/devise/models/validatable.rb:16:in `included'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p369/gems/devise-1.0.5/lib/devise/models.rb:66:in`include'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p369/gems/devise-1.0.5/lib/devise/models.rb:66:in `devise'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p369/gems/devise-1.0.5/lib/devise/models.rb:65:in`each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p369/gems/devise-1.0.5/lib/devise/models.rb:65:in `devise'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p369/gems/devise-1.0.5/lib/devise/orm/active_record.rb:24:in`included_modules_hook'
     ... 37 levels...
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p369/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/commands/generate.rb:1
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.6-p369/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.6-p369/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in`require'
    from script/generate:3

Answer (score 0):

check the devise group on google groups

http://groups.google.com/group/plataformatec-devise

that's the better forum to ask this question

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should look into initializers/devise.rb. There are some instructions on setting those keys. Plus, please refer to http://asciicasts.com/episodes/210-customizing-devise, http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/tag/subdomain/.

I didn't use devise with RoR 2.3.x, only with 3.0.x. That could be the difference.

Hope that helps. Let us know :)